# Large Composition Operator?

Tags: functions, notation

Doing composition of functions with my students and was wondering if there was a large composition operator similar to Sigma and Pi?  What I'm thinking is composing a function n times...
$$(f\circ f\circ ... \circ f)(x)=f(f(...(f(x))...))=\circ_{i=1}^n{f}$$.

Not an overly important question, but i would love to maybe illustrate this to some of the more exceptional kids in my class who are aware of operators such as $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$.

Comment: The usual notation is $f^n$.

Comment: that's it?...Thanks!

Comment: Just be careful to explicitly define it that way, mostly to avoid confusion with notation like $\cos^{2}$, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get really deep, consider chapter 2.4 of Cowen & MacCluer's book, Composition Operators on Spaces of Analytic Functions [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WWMI52-GX_oC&q=iteration#v=snippet&q=iteration&f=false). Actually, this iteration of composition is a primary tool! Their setting is usually $H^2$, the Hardy space of analytic functions on the disk (roughly the functions which are square integrable on the unit circle, and have a taylor series on the disk). Fix a function, $\phi$ then map a function $f$ in $H^2$ to $f\circ \phi$ (also in $H^2$!). To study this linear map on $H^2$ (it's just a matrix if you like linear algebra), iterating it it very important!